# Supermicro BIOS upgrade : Error when sending enable message to ME

Tags: bios, supermicro

I recently upgraded my BIOS on my [X9SCL-F](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c202_c204/x9scl-f.cfm) board from version 1.1 to 2.2. It seems to be a 2 step process where after you create a bootable DOS USB, you need to run `AMI_1.BAT x9scm-f.202` Once this process is completed, it mentions to reboot the server and boot back into the DOS USB and run AMI2.BAT which I believe is generated during step 1.

I rebooted back into the DOS USB and upon running AMI2.BAT I get `Error when sending enable message to ME`

I found this [Fix X9SCM-F BIOS update failure](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Fix_X9SCM-F_BIOS_update_failure_Error_when_sending_Enable_Message_to_ME) which seemed to be flashing it with a different BIOS file. I am not sure why we would need to flash it with a different BIOS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error message is expected if JPME1 and JPME2 are not enabled. I did not have the jumper pins on my board, so I simply used 2 small screwdrivers to short the JPME1(pins 1 & 2) with one and JPME2(pins 1 & 2) with another.

You need to keep a steady hand throughout the step 2 of calling `AMI2.BAT` but it doesn't take more than a few seconds. On completion you should see

```
Reading file............done
FFS checksums...........ok
Input the ME data into the BIOS.....done
- Update success for /FDT!!
- Successful Update Recovery Loader to OPRx!!
- Successful Update FPT, MFSB, FTPR, and MFS!!
- ME Entire Image update success !!
- WARNING : System must be power-off to have the changes take effect!
```

Reboot and go into the BIOS (by hitting Del a few times on POST) and check the BIOS version number. It should be upgraded to 2.2