# What is ME region in BIOS

Tags: bios, supermicro

What is ME region in BIOS. We have a Supermicro board and when I upgrade BIOS, we are getting an option 'Preserve ME region'. Not sure what it is. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should include more information on the board that you have to get a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 4):

BIOS ME stands for "BIOS Management Engine". You want to have that option unchecked when upgrading your BIOS.

You haven't specified what board you have, but for my X9SCL-F, I had a problem when upgrading the BIOS and I got this error:

> Error when sending enable message to ME

and here's how I fixed it. See [my thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/871284/supermicro-bios-upgrade-error-when-sending-enable-message-to-me).